# Trying to display specific table after recordset (php+mysql)

Tags: loops, recordset

I'll appreciate if someone help me solve this! I know that must be simple, but I couldn't do it. What I got is a script that basically query a database and put its data in a table like this:

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

include 'conn.php';

$curso = "UC001";
$data_recebimento = date("d-m-y", time());
$empresa = "ISAT";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM apontamentos WHERE idcurso='".$curso."' ORDER BY licao, tela ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Erro: ".mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
    echo "<h2>There are no records for this ".$curso."!</h2>";
}else{

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    /*header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=apontamentos_".$curso."_".$data_recebimento.".xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");*/

?>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Apontamentos do Curso "<?php echo $curso ?>" (<?php echo $empresa ?>) - <?php echo date("d/m/y, H:i:s", time()); ?></th>
        </tr>
<?php   
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Lesson <?php echo $row["licao"] ?></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Part <?php echo $row["tela"] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <th>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
                <th>Data cria&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
                <th>Data modifica&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Anima&ccedil;&otilde;es</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["animacoes"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Exerc&iacute;cios</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["exercicios"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Ilustra&ccedil;&otilde;es</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["ilustracoes"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Navega&ccedil;&atilde;o</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["navegacao"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Textos</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["textos"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Outros</strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["outros"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php
    }
}

mysql_close();
?>
            </table>
```

So, what I need is that this line:

```
<tr><th colspan="4">Lesson <?php echo $row["licao"] ?></th><tr>
```

which is a title of the Lesson, appear once before it prints its parts (Part 1, Part 2...). What I got by far is Lesson 1 appearing after each Part. Would it be simple to solve? I've tried to put ON ROLLUP but I'm not sure if it's the right way. I'm lost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because this code:

```
<tr>
   <th colspan="4">Lesson <?php echo $row["licao"] ?></th>
</tr>
```

is inside `while` loop so Lesson will be displayed along with everytime Part is printed. As I understand, you want Lesson title to be printed only once, right? Since I can't know your code so well, here is what I can think of quickly (please look around your `while` loop):

```
<?php
    require_once('../config.php');

    include 'conn.php';

    $curso = "UC001";
    $data_recebimento = date("d-m-y", time());
    $empresa = "ISAT";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM apontamentos WHERE idcurso='".$curso."' ORDER BY licao, tela ASC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Erro: ".mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
        echo "<h2>There are no records for this ".$curso."!</h2>";
    }else{

        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        /*header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=apontamentos_".$curso."_".$data_recebimento.".xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");*/

    ?>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Apontamentos do Curso "<?php echo $curso ?>" (<?php echo $empresa ?>) - <?php echo date("d/m/y, H:i:s", time()); ?></th>
            </tr>
    <?php   
        $currentLesson = ''; // ADDED: Declare a 'flag' variable here to keep track what current lesson is inside while loop
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
         <?php
            if ($currentLesson != $row["licao"]) { // If currentLesson != current 'licao'
                $currentLesson = $row["licao"]; // then assign it to keep track
                echo '<tr>
                    <th colspan="4">Lesson ' . $row["licao"] . '</th>
                </tr>'; // Then output current Lesson
                // From now on, them same lesson title shouldn't be printed until we meet new lesson title
                // I don't know much about PHP and HTML mixing syntax, so I used echo just to be safe. You can do it in a better syntax.
               // DONE
         }
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">Part <?php echo $row["tela"] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <th>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
                    <th>Data cria&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
                    <th>Data modifica&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Anima&ccedil;&otilde;es</strong></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["animacoes"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Exerc&iacute;cios</strong></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["exercicios"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Ilustra&ccedil;&otilde;es</strong></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["ilustracoes"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Navega&ccedil;&atilde;o</strong></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["navegacao"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Textos</strong></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["textos"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Outros</strong></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["outros"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_criacao"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["data_modificacao"] ?></td>
                </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }

    mysql_close();
    ?>
                </table>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi @TrinhIT! Thank you so much for your help, your solution worked! It was simple as I thought it were, but I couldn't get to it before. It happens a lot when you work alone :)

Thanks again!